# Hover on inside element and change whole div background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve when hover one of it child element then change the main div background with class name `search-block`. The issue is that I have multiple blocks so it's changing the background of every block which I don't want. This is my code:

```js
$('.btn').hover(function() {
  $('.search-block').addClass('search-boxshadow');
}, function() {
  $('.search-block').removeClass('search-boxshadow')
});
```

```css
.search-boxshadow {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
  <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tablerow">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
          <span>05/07/2018</span>
          <a class="btn hidden-xs" href="#">PRIMARY</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
  <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tablerow">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
          <span>05/07/2018</span>
          <a class="btn hidden-xs" href="#">PRIMARY</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to use DOM traversal to find the parent `.search-block` of the element which was hovered. To do that in jQuery you can use `closest()`.

Also note that you can make the code more succinct by providing a single handler function to `hover()` which runs under both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and call `toggleClass()` in both cases. Try this:

```js
$('.btn').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.search-block').toggleClass('search-boxshadow');
});
```

```css
.search-boxshadow {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
  <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tablerow">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
          <span>05/07/2018</span>
          <a class="btn hidden-xs" href="#">PRIMARY</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
  <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="tablerow">
      <div class="tablecell">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
          <span>05/07/2018</span>
          <a class="btn hidden-xs" href="#">PRIMARY</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To target a specific parent based on className you can do the following:

```
$('.btn-list').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.parentClass').toggleClass('test')
});
```

Comment: Note that `closest()` is preferred in cases where you only want to retrieve a single ancestor element, as it stops on the first match.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can do it with pure CSS:

```css
.search-block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
    <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablecell">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
            <span>05/07/2018</span>
            <a class="btn " href="#">PRIMARY</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-eq-height search-block pers-load">
    <div class="col-lg-12 add flush col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablecell">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <blockquote>COnatct</blockquote>
            <span>05/07/2018</span>
            <a class="btn" href="#">PRIMARY</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```